# Chainlink node setup - "Failed to run migration 0003_eth_logs_table"

Tags: chainlink

When I try running

```
cd ~/.chainlink-rinkeby && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-rinkeby:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.14 local n
```

I receive the following error:

```
creating application: failed to initialize ORM: initializeORM#Migrate: failed to run migration 0003_eth_logs_table: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INCLUDE" (SQLSTATE 42601)
```

Following the instructions from the "running a node" chainlink instructions. Has anyone else run into this issue or know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Might need more context than just this. I haven't seen this error before.

Comment: For more context, I have the Link node running on an ubuntu 20 server vm, and the postgres running on the host (windows 10). There doesn't seem to be any connectivity or authentication problem with the node reaching the db. I found the same issue looking through the discord "https://discord.com/channels/592041321326182401/592043790005567499/854343667413155872" In that convo he claims "In migrations table, there's no row where id = '0003_eth_logs_table'"

Comment: hmmm... might make sense to kill the DB and start again. Assuming you're just getting setup yes?

Comment: I reinstalled postgres and ran a new VM and its working. The only difference was I kept the locale default instead of my region when installing POSTGRES -unsure if that actually has any effect.

Comment: odd... Glad it working now!